# No entiendo la solución de esta función con el ciclo for e if

Tags: javascript, string, bucle-for

```
function numberOfCharacters(string) {
  //La función recibe un string. Recorre el srting y devuelve el caracter con el número de veces que aparece 
  //en formato par clave-valor.
  //Ej: Recibe ---> "adsjfdsfsfjsdjfhacabcsbajda" || Devuelve ---> { a: 5, b: 2, c: 2, d: 4, f: 4, h:1, j: 4, s: 5 } 
  //Escribe tu código aquí abajo

  let obj = {};

  for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    if(!obj[string[i]]){
      obj[string[i]] = 0;
    }  
    obj[string[i]] += 1;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Lo que no entiendo son las evaluaciones del if, por qué 0 en la primera parte, y += 1 en la segunda, cómo está verificando que ese string tenga valores repetidos o no? Por favor necesitaría una explicación. Gracias

Comment: Evalúa que lo que mandas en la posición del objeto en ese momento, que es un string, no exista o _"no este repetido"_ y si no lo está, es **false**, inicializa la variable en 0, de caso contrario suma una vez por sí mismo el valor con el que se haya encontrado a esa variable. Eso es, básicamente lo que hace el programa. Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hace primero con el `if(!obj[string[i]])` es inicializar el objeto en la clave `string[i]` para que cuando llegue al sumatorio `obj[string[i]] += 1;` funcione correctamente.

Si no se inicializa con algún valor valdría NaN  y `NaN + 1 = NaN` por lo que no se acumularía nada.

Un ejemplo sencillo sería:

```js
obj = {};

obj['a'] = 1;
obj['a'] += 1;
obj['b'] += 1;


console.log(obj)
```